is there a way to print the variables name and content so that i dont have to everytime i want to examine object?
is there a way to print the variables name and content so that i dont have to everytime i want to examine object?
I think that dart does not save that information but i just wanted to make sure with experts.
goal:
create a method that prints the inputed variable name and its content.
issue:
chatgpt/claude dont know how.
I cant find a stackoverflow.
I think its not possible
Example use:
code::
Map<String, dynamic> body = {"name":"juan"}
printVariable(body); 


void printVariable(dynamic data){

}

output(does not have to be exact)
body : {"name":"juan"}

Everything i tried does not work.

Take a look at this post to see why it's not possible to get a variable's name based on its value. However, that post does mention some possibilities when using reflection.

No. In general, Dart does not retain variable names at runtime, and there is no way to go from a code reference like data to a string "data".
You have to do: printVariable("data", data);
(If there was a way, ArgumentError.value would have used it.)
